# Why do we have to explicitly specify the entities while creating a Room Database as the entities are already annotated?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

While using `Room Persistence Library`, I wonder why we have to explicitly specify the entities while creating a `RoomDatabase` as the entities are already annotated with `@Entity` annotation. I mean We could simply skip the `entities` attribute of the `@Database` annotation.

Comment: An app might have more than one `RoomDatabase`.

Answer (score 0):

It's still useful. Sure we could remove it but:

- Can't/convinent way to specify some the other things we can specify in that annotation as arguments in there.
- It describes the intention, this is important. This means that other parts (tools/IDE) can check if this really is an Entity you are trying to fetch or if a mistake was made.
- As a marker "interface", related to the previous point, but to simply communicate what it is and easily find them.
- Tools/lib/frameworks might/probably need/want it as they can generate stuff/shadow classes/subclasses or such things. At least for analysis, related to first 1st and 2nd point as well.

For example see the [EntityProcessor](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev/room/compiler/src/main/kotlin/androidx/room/processor/EntityProcessor.kt) in the source for Room.